# Navigating in a WinJS app always throws an exception

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

Every time I try to perform a navigation in the ready function of a page, the application crashes.

Specifically, it fails at the `WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/login/login.html", {});` line below:

```
// This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
// populates the page elements with the app's data.
ready: function (element, options) {            

    var listView = element.querySelector(".groupeditemslist").winControl;
    listView.groupHeaderTemplate = element.querySelector(".headertemplate");
    listView.itemTemplate = element.querySelector(".itemtemplate");
    listView.oniteminvoked = this._itemInvoked.bind(this);

    // Set up a keyboard shortcut (ctrl + alt + g) to navigate to the
    // current group when not in snapped mode.
    listView.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        if (appView.value !== appViewState.snapped && e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === WinJS.Utilities.Key.g && e.altKey) {
            var data = listView.itemDataSource.list.getAt(listView.currentItem.index);
            this.navigateToGroup(data.group.key);
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    }.bind(this), true);

    this._initializeLayout(listView, appView.value);
    listView.element.focus();

    initialize();
}

function initialize() {
    // Check if user is logged in
    if (is_logged_in !== true) {
        WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/login/login.html", {});
    }
    else {
        // TODO: Replace the data with your real data.
        // You can add data from asynchronous sources whenever it becomes available.
        generateSampleData().forEach(function (item) {
            list.push(item);
        });
    }
}
```

Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple routes you could take here:

1. Catch the unhandled exception and ignore it
2. Structure your code to avoid setting up the error condition

To ignore the error you can setup a WinJS.Application.onerror handler that can deal with unhandled exceptions. Here's a forum post that guides you in this solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/686188b3-852d-45d5-a376-13115dbc889d

In general, I'd say you're better off avoiding the exception all together. To that end - What's happening here is that only one navigation event (promise) can occur at a time. The navigation promise used to navigate to groupedItems is still running when you're inside of the ready function. When you call initialize, which then calls WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/login/login.html", {}); it sees this and tries to first cancel the currently running navigation promise which results in the exception you're seeing.

Instead, you can use the [window.setImmediate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453394.aspx) function to setup your call to initialize() to run after the current script block exits. To do this, replace your call to initialize() with:

```
window.setImmediate(this.initialize.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

If your running your code on the RTM version after coming from the Release Preview this should sort your problem.

```
function initialize() {
    // Check if user is logged in
    if (is_logged_in !== true) {
        WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/login/login.html", {});
    }
    else {
        // TODO: Replace the data with your real data.
        // You can add data from asynchronous sources whenever it becomes available.
        generateSampleData().forEach(function (item) {
            list.push(item);
        });
    }
}

var markSupportedForProcessing = WinJS.Utilities.markSupportedForProcessing;
var requireSupportedForProcessing = WinJS.Utilities.requireSupportedForProcessing;

markSupportedForProcessing(initialize);
requireSupportedForProcessing(initialize);
```

You should probably take a look at the migration docs which details what the above is actually for and why: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30706

Comment: Tried your code, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Also, I experience this on a completely new RTM project.

Comment: Also check your text data-bindings in the view.

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no information in the debugger other than the `data.description` property in the `terminateAppHandler` function which is `{"description":"Canceled","name":"Canceled"`